# how to pass parameter from MVC4 application to worker role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-worker-roles

how to pass parameter from MVC4 application to worker role?

i need to pass at least a string from my mvc application to worker role

Answer (score 1):

Use a queuing(PUSH) mechanism or a database(INTERVAL PULLING). There is no direct way to establish communication.